# Ehcache: storing null to indicate missing value vs. "not cached yet"?

Tags: ehcache

I would like to use Ehcache in the "cache-as-sor" configuration (read-through + write-through), so it would hide database interaction from the parent process.

In my case, it can happen that for a requested key, the corresponding value does not exist at all in the underlying database. So, in order to avoid querying database every time get(key) is called for a non-existent value, I would like to store in the cache the fact that the value is missing. The first thing that comes to my mind is to store null values for that; so, if ehcache.containsKey(key) returns false, I need to consult the database and update the cache; but if ehcache.containsKey(key) returns true but ehcache.get(key) returns null, it means the value will never be there and I don't have to query the DB.

However, the Ehcache documentation states that put(key, null) [is not allowed](http://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/3.6.1/index.html).

How to handle such scenario then?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `NullObject`. So instead of storing `null`, you store some object that you know represents `null`.